# Как в Intelij Idea сделать set JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java

у меня при запуске выдается сообщение

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0

и не открывается порт 8080.

я так понимаю что где то стоит лишняя настройка  MaxPermSize, но не могу понять как ее удалить.

Comment: Касательно `MaxPermSize=256M`. Эта настройка лежит в `bin/idea.vmoptions` или `bin/idea64.vmoptions` относительно каталога Idea. Говорит он тебе о том, что эта настройка устарела, и более не поддерживается. Это никак не влияет на работоспособность. Касательно порта 8080 у тебя где-то должна быть другая ошибка. Но тебе надо описать, как ты диагностировал, что у тебя не открывается порт 8080, и почему он вообще должен открываться.

Comment: все правильно ,нужно удалить MaxPeremSize ,но ее нет в файлах vmoptions .пока не удалишь сервер не запустится к сожалению.где ее эту опцию искать неизвестно .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это всего лишь предупреждение, само по себе наличие параметра `MaxPermSize` не препятствует работе. Но появление этого предупреждения сигнализирует о том, что вы пытаетесь в Java 9 или более поздней запустить приложение разработанное для использования с Java 8. Судя по номеру порта, это может быть Glassfish, у которого в корне дистрибутива лежит файл README.txt, в котором в свою очередь есть строчки

```
0. Prerequisite
===============

GlassFish 5.0 requires Oracle JDK 8 Update 144.
Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html to download the JDK.
```

Либо откатитесь к Java 8, либо используйте ПО совместимое со свежими версиями Java. Например [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/).